# How to get text within DIV beside SPAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm building a scraper and I've come across some HTML I don't know how to parse. I have a piece of code like this.

```
<div>
  <span>SomeHeader</span>
  "Some text"

  <span>SomeOtherHeader</span>
  "More text"
</div>
```

In JS or JQuery, I want to find "SomeHeader", and look for the "Sometext" after it without the "More Text".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$('div span:contains(SomeHeader)').get(0).nextSibling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:contains()` selector to find element contain some text but this selector isn't exact. For example `$("span:contains(Text)")` select both of span in bottom.

```
<span>Text</span>
<span>Text text</span>
```

You need to use `.filter( function )` method to check text of element exactly, then select element. When you selected element, use `nextSibling` property to get sibling text of element.

```js
var targetSpan = $("div > span").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "SomeHeader";
});
var text = targetSpan[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>SomeHeader</span>
  "Some text"
  <span>SomeOtherHeader</span>
  "More text"
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After you get reference to the DIV element, you can use its "textContent()" method to extract all the text in the DIV element and its children.  Then it's just a matter of finding the occurrence of what you're looking for.  You could use a Regular Expression, like "/SomeHeader*/", then "/SomeOtherHeader/", to extract what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this :

```
$('div')
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
        if($(this).text() == "SomeHeader") {
          alert($(this)[0].nextSibling.nodeValue);
        }
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/bko2wsbu/1/